# What is the purpose of: @synthesize variableName = __ variableName;

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7

In my Xcode Apple template, managedObjectContext is synthesised in AppDelegate.m like this:

```
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
```

I’ve never understood the  **= __managedObjectContext;** part. Please could someone explain?
(Is it to call the method ‘managedObjectContext’?)

Thanks.

Comment: There is no purpose any more. If you read the documentation you would have found out that this is done automatically for you now so you don't need it.

Comment: I tried several times but each time I woke up hours later, none the wiser. Please forgive me.

Comment: Did you read the Encapsulating Data part of the Apple documentation? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html This document will explain it all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's to give the backing instance variable the name `__managedObjectContext`. If you just `@synthesize managedObjectContext`, the backing variable is named `managedObjectContext`.

With this `@synthesize`, though, it's as if you typed:

```
@implementation MyObject {
    ManagedObjectContextType __managedObjectContext;
}

- (ManagedObjectContextType)managedObjectContextType {
    return __managedObjectContext;
}

- (void)setManagedObjectContext:(ManagedObjectContextType *)managedObjectContext {
    __managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext;
}
```

(Yes, I'm simplifying a bit.)

Previously, `@synthesize` was required. Now, in most cases you can skip it. When you skip it, it's the equivalent of `@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext` (note single underscore).

It still has some use: If you don't include a `@synthesize` statement but do include a setter/getter, the compiler will not create a backing variable for you automatically. You can do so even though you're including a getter/setter by including `@synthesize thing = _thing`.

Comment: Thanks Steven, that makes things much clearer! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Good question.

You can see the declaration of the variable `managedObjectContext` in `AppDelegate.h` file of your project i.e,

```
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

For the variables which are declared as **`readonly`**, we can't be able to assign any values. But, for the one who has created the variable as `readonly` should assign a value in his program. So, for this he is **storing or referencing the same variable by synthesising it** and with this he could use the `self.managedObjectContext` or `_managedObjectContext` variable as a local or private variable `managedObjectContext`.

Comment: Well actually there is a way to assign to a readonly property.

Comment: @Popeye Do you mean the other way?

Comment: No. Basically you could have the property like `@property (readonly, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;` in your `.h` file so it is public so other classes see it as public which is fine (Correct) and you could have `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;` declared in the private interface in your `.m` file which will create a setter for that class so you can set the variable anywhere in that class (correct).

Comment: Now this is where it can go wrong (and is really) but can still be done you declare a public method that calls the setter that is private which would mean because that method is public a user could still set the property even though it is readonly. I've come to learn nothing is totally private and there are hacky ways of doing it. Please note I'm wasn't saying your answer was wrong just thought I would throw a different spin on it +1

Comment: Yeah yeah, got you! You made me understand the new way of assigning values to `readonly` variables very easily. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I will say it is bad practice to do this though because if you wanted to give a property a setter then there is no point in declaring it `readonly` that would just make it redundant. Glad I could give a different spin on it for you.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a @property 2 method are being generated - a getter and a setter. 
The default  for a property name x , i.e @property x, is:

```
-(void) setX:(int)x;
-(int) x;
```

Every time you call self.x the getter/setter being called.

In order to access the instance variable directly you need to call _x.

If you wish to call x without the underscore you should use:

```
 @synthsize x = _x;
```

Comment: In Cocoa, the word “get” in method names usually indicates the use of an output parameter, not a getter. (Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-1004202 )

Comment: As `Tuukka Norri` has said there is no `get` in the getter methods name and because of this your answer is incorrect.

Comment: I confused - Fixed it. 
Thank you